# Python, VIM: namespace, scope, life of a python object stuck in a << HERE

Tags: python, vim

If i have two functions:

```
function! foo()
python3 << HERE
 import mylib
 pass
HERE

function! bar()
python3 << HERE
 import mylib
 pass
HERE
```

The src says:

```
 1. Python interpreter main program
 3. Implementation of the Vim module for Python
```

So, is the python interpreter embedded in vim AND additionally, are separate extensions to python provided (wrapper functions for the VIM API)

How many times is mylib compiled to bytecode and loaded? Does each vimscript function get its own mylib - can I instantiate something and expect it to be visible in the other function? I have a bunch of leader functions that share similar code and act on the same buffer so I wanted to know if I could reuse that data-structure.
How many times is the interpreter loaded into memory: once obviously at vim runtime.

Comment: I believe the interpreter is loaded once and that all python blocks use the same interpreter regardless of where they are called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Python interpreter is indeed loaded once.
2. Python interpreter caches imported modules in `sys.modules`, so mylib is loaded once per Vim instance.
3. Python interpreter caches compiled bytecode in the `*.pyc` files on the filesystem, so mylib is compiled once per its update (assuming Python was able to detect this update; usually it has no problems with this).

---

In any case, do never use `python << EOF`, all plugins should always use namespaced functions: e.g.

Bad:

```
python << EOF
from y import foo, bar

def my_function1():
    foo()

def my_function2(i):
    bar(i)

for i in range(2):
    my_function1()
    my_function2(i)
EOF
```

Good:

```
# pythonx/mymodule.py
from y import foo, bar

def my_function1():
    foo()

def my_function2(i):
    bar(i)

def start():
    for i in range(2):
        my_function1()
        my_function2(i)

" plugin/myscript.vim
python import mymodule; mymodule.start()
```

Reasoning:

1. In the above example all of `my_function1`, `my_function2`, `foo`, `bar`, `i` appear in the `__main__` module global namespace. If you install some plugin which does not follow good practices (there are lots of them) and it appears to define different `foo` or `bar` your plugin will not work. Or that plugin will not work if it happened to be loaded before yours.
2. `python << EOF` is recompiled each time it is called.

Comment: Where would that `pythonx/mymodule.py` be located? If I wanted to distribute my Vim plugin, could that be put under `~/.vim`, so that it is included in the Vimball?

Comment: @IngoKarkat Anywhere in `&runtimepath` as usual. You need relatively recent version of Vim though (AFAIR there were some fixes after 7.4) or you will have to modify `sys.path` or create the same import hook (I had a Python-only version of the code used for hook for testing purposes, but am not sure whether I actually posted it anywhere). More details at `:h pythonx-directory`.

Comment: Ah, I have put this Python-only version in the help file. Do not remember whether it is the most recent one though.